# MySQL: Migrate from table with flag to mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently we have a table 'news' with the following relevant fields:

- id
- is_topnews

Now a system-wide table 'category' was introduced with the following relevant fields:

- id

The category 'Top' (generic category used for 'topnews' too) was inserted with 'id' '4', as you may see in the query below.

And a related mapping table 'category_mm' with the following fields:

- source_table
- source_id
- category_id

Now I have to create entries in the mapping table for all 'news' having 'is_topnews' set to '1'. I tried it with the following query but without success, error message says that I have an error in my syntax near 'FROM [...]':

```
INSERT INTO category_mm
      SET category_mm.source_table = 'news',
          category_mm.source_id = news.id, 
          category_mm.category_id = 4 FROM news 
      WHERE news.is_topnews = 1;
```

Can this be done in plain (My-)SQL somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
INSERT INTO category_mm (source_table, source_id, category_id)
(SELECT 'news', news.id, 4 FROM news WHERE news.is_topnews = 1)
```

Comment: As a note, the parentheses around the `select` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
INSERT INTO category_mm (source_table, source_id, category_id)
VALUES (SELECT 'news', news.id, 4 FROM news WHERE news.is_topnews = 1);
```